# How to fit 12t of cargo into Sidewinder MkI?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have seen on the [Elite Dangerous wiki](https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Sidewinder_MkI) that Sidewinder has a maximum capacity of 12 tonnes. My own sidewinder currently carries 8 tonnes - it has one 2E rack and two 1E racks.

I don't know how to increase the capacity any more. When I go to the market, I can't replace the 1E racks with the 2E racks.

So how can I get to full 12t of capacity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sidewinder MkI actually has a maximum cargo capacity of 16T foregoing shields, but you can achieve a 12T cargo capacity by equipping one 2E cargo rack, four 1E cargo racks, and a class 2 shield generator [like so](https://s.orbis.zone/9oR5). You can then gain an additional 4T of capacity by replacing the shield generator with a cargo rack, but the better option by far would be to play it safe in the Sidewinder and save up for a Hauler.

Comment: It should be noted that not every module is available at every station (at least, as far as new players are concerned). That might also be why it seemed impossible to find cargo rack upgrades at whichever station the OP was docked at. Once you get far enough into the game, you'll have easy access to stations that do stock every possible module.

Comment: @Ellesedil this is true, but the 1E cargo rack in particular is extremely common